# Посчитать колличество одинаковых заказов в объекте

Tags: javascript

```
{
    "tableName":"Table №1",
    "order": [
        {"id":1652535803920,"price":"5","name":"Fish"},
        {"id":1652535886394,"price":"5","name":"Fish"},
        {"id":1652535889066,"price":"5","name":"Salade"},
        {"id":1652539922675,"price":"5","name":"Salade"},
        {"id":1652539938561, "price":"5","name":"Salade"}
    ],
    "isTake":true,
    "sum":0,
    "id":"1"
}
```

Не могу додуматься как посчитать количество одинаковых заказов, что б вернуть массив объектов

```
Order2 // [{name: Fish, count: 2}, {name: Salade, count: 3}
```

Comment: @Grundy, если честно думаю стоит хотябы объяснять как светси случай одинаковых примитивных элементов в массиве к случаю, когда это объекты, а не с ходу закрывать как дубликат к общему алгоритму

Comment: К сожалению не могу дать полноценный ответ, потому дам ответ как можно подробно в комментариях. Основная суть - это свести случай с объектами к случаю примитивных данных. Один из самых простых способов - это по набору данных объекта собрать уникальный ключ, который будет представлять набор объектов. Обычно если уже есть `id` (на примере ваших данных) делают такой ключ `key = '${item.id}'`. Если допустим его нет, то можно было бы сгруппировать цену и название: `key = ${item.price}-${item.name}`, тогда вы бы различали элементы, у которых одинаковые названия, но разные цены

Comment: Но насколько я понимаю, вам нужно смотреть только на название, т.е. вам по сути ключ нужен вида `key = ${item.name}`. Это значит что в строке `acc[el] = (acc[el] || 0) + 1` ключ `el`, заменить на `el.name`. Но таким образом вы получите объект вида: `{[el.name]: repeatCount, ...}`. Теперь надо преобразовать получившийся объект в массив. Это мы уже можем сделать с помощью цикла `for in`. Заранее извинясь, что приходится код писать в комментариях, просто скопируйте куда вам угодно и приведите в читабельный вид

Comment: ```const repeatedObjectsCount = [];

for (const key in result) {
    repeatedObjectsCount.push({name: key, count: result[key]})
}
```

Comment: Надеюсь смог помочь